# Expo app is throwing when locally hosted api is called

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo in my project and I hosted a local server for API. When I try connecting the API with the expo project it gives me network error:

```js
error Error: Network Error
    at createError (F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:117:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:609:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:396:12)
    at F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:517:9
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\_EventEmitter.js:135:33)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:27)
    at F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:12
    at MessageQueue.__guard (F:\Projects\react-native-food-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:9)
```

This is the code for API calling

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
});
```

It works just fine in insomnia but throws an error when I call the API in expo

Answer (score 1):

expo is not support localhost server.

you must use the ip instead of localhost

```sh
ipconfig #window
networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi #mac
```

and then

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://192.168.0.100:8000/api/",
});
```